# Loading data incrementally Collectionview MAUI with RemainingItemsCommand

Tags: maui, collectionview

I have a Page with a collectionview and is working fine, but currently, I am trying to implement RemainingItemsThresholdReachedCommand with no success. The problem is that the command is continously firing even without scrolling the collection and also, the scrolling of the collection gets very laggy when the command is enable.

The collection is inside a Grid and the Grid is inside a Scrollview, like this:

```
<Scrollview>
  <Grid>
    <CollectionView>
    </CollectionView>
  </Grid>
</Scrollview>
```

This is my code.

XAML

```
  <CollectionView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Messages}" SelectionMode="None" BackgroundColor="{AppThemeBinding Dark=Black,Light=White}" RemainingItemsThreshold="0" RemainingItemsThresholdReachedCommand="{Binding RemainingItemsCommand}">
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
             <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:MessagesMessages">

             </DataTemplate>
         </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
```

ViewModel

```
public partial class MessagesPageViewModel : ObservableObject
{
   public ObservableCollection<MessagesMessages> Messages { get; set; } = new();

    [RelayCommand]
    private void RemainingItems()
    {
        LoadMessages();
    }
   public MessagesPageViewModel(IApiService apiService)
    {
       apiService = apiService;
       LoadMessages();
    }

   private async void LoadMessages()
   {
      Messages.Add(...)
   }
}
```

I have tried to change the RemainingItemsThreshold value to every number and it does not work as expected. I am retreiving data from an API in packages of 10 messages, and the first load fill the entire screen, but without scrolling, the command continue to fire.

[image]

Comment: Could you please show more code about viewmodel to help us reproduce this issue?

Comment: I updated the question with the viewmodel

Comment: May I ask how you fill the entire screen for the first time?

Comment: I get the info through an API

Comment: I know it. But you say first time you fill the screen. How you estimate the numbers of items to fill the screen?

Comment: I request the number of items that I want to the API and because all the items have the same height, I can tell how many do I need to fill the screen. I am currently trying with 20 items and the command doesn´t fire without scrolling, but when I scroll to the last item, the command fires multiply times.

Comment: Have you tried set a HeightRequest for a CollectionView?

Answer (score 0):

It's not recommended to wrap a vertically-scrolling **CollectionView** inside a vertically-scrolling **ScrollView**. **CollectionViews** have their own scrolling built in so you don't have to put it in a **ScrollView**. Otherwise, it will cause many scrolling issues. If you still want to put it in a scrollview, try to set the HeightRequest of the CollectionView.

For more info, you could refer to: [CollectionView requires ScrollView
#8097](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/8097#issuecomment-1249662389), [How to use CollectionView inside a ScrollView](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/133556).

Comment: This doesn't solve te issue and I was aware of the built-in scroll of the collectionview  and that i doesn´t need the scrollview but the performance of the scroll without the scrollview is so bad and laggy. Without the scrollview, the RemainingItemsCommand still doesn´t work as expected.

Comment: you may also try ```RemainingItemsThresholdReached="OnCollectionViewRemainingItemsThresholdReached"``` in xaml. Does this event continue firing even without collectionview scrolling?

Answer (score -1):

As not to let this come to a dead end.

Here are some helpful definitions and a link to more info on incremental loading with `CollectionView` in MAUI.

- `RemainingItemsThreshold`, of type `int`, the threshold of items not yet visible in the list at which the `RemainingItemsThresholdReached` event will be fired.
- `RemainingItemsThresholdReachedCommand`, of type xref:System.Windows.Input.ICommand, which is executed when the `RemainingItemsThreshold` is reached.
- `RemainingItemsThresholdReachedCommandParameter`, of type `object`, which is the parameter that's passed to the `RemainingItemsThresholdReachedCommand`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/collectionview/populate-data?view=net-maui-8.0#load-data-incrementally